# Elasticsearch how to index an existing json file

Tags: elasticsearch

I use a *PUT* command:

```
curl -PUT "http://localhost:9200/music/lyrics/2" --data-binary @D:\simple\caseyjones.json
```

caseyjones.json:

```
{
    "artist": "Wallace Saunders",
    "year": 1909,
    "styles": ["traditional"],
    "album": "Unknown",
    "name": "Ballad of Casey Jones",
    "lyrics": "Come all you rounders if you want to hear
            The story of a brave engineer
            Casey Jones was the rounder's name....
            Come all you rounders if you want to hear
            The story of a brave engineer
            Casey Jones was the rounder's name
            On the six-eight wheeler, boys, he won his fame
            The caller called Casey at half past four
            He kissed his wife at the station door
            He mounted to the cabin with the orders in his hand
            And he took his farewell trip to that promis'd land

            Chorus:
            Casey Jones--mounted to his cabin
            Casey Jones--with his orders in his hand
            Casey Jones--mounted to his cabin
            And he took his... land"
}
```

**Warning:** failed to parse, document is empty. But log has show contents of *.json file.
[image: Elasticsearch Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](http://json.org/) does not allow line-breaks. So, you need to replace all the line breaks with \n (platform specific) and store the text as a single line.

Like:

```
{
    "artist": "Wallace Saunders",
    "year": 1909,
    "styles": ["traditional"],
    "album": "Unknown",
    "name": "Ballad of Casey Jones",
    "lyrics": "Come all you rounders if you want to hear\nThe story of a brave engineer\nCasey Jones was the rounder's name...."
}
```